# How do I force Juju to deploy a fresh charm, not a cached one?

Tags: juju

Is there a way with juju commands to clear the juju charm cache for a particular charm from a running bootstrap node?

I'm writing a charm and for during development when I've made changes to a charm but don't commit a revision update I want to be able to iterate quicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-u` option to `juju deploy` to speed iteration during development of your charms:

```
  -u, --upgrade         Deploy the charm on disk, increments revision if
                        needed
```

e.g.,

```
juju deploy -u charm-name
```

Comment: Does this actually force juju's charm cache to clear itself?  For example, I tried the `-u` switch after rewriting a charm and resetting its revision 0.  Juju kept using its cached version and would not take my new version from disk.

Comment: It doesn't _clear_ the cache, but it should force the updated version to be deployed...

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried this and got:

> $ juju deploy -u --repository=./charms local:trusty/node-app openmotion
>
> Added charm "local:trusty/node-app-24" to the environment.
> --upgrade (or -u) is deprecated and ignored; charms are always deployed with a unique revision.`

So it seems -u is no longer necessary, at least as of juju 1.18.